# "Editable" Data Table vs Table

Tags: ibm-bpm, brazos

Can someone help me to decide when i should use The Table component over the Data Table with "Editable" option selected?.

I know the logic approach could be to consider the amount of information the table will present in the coach and Choose Data Table for large chunks of data, however, with the capabilities of the normal Table (Pre-load, Lazy load) is not clear when to use one over the other.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the Data Table control with "Editable" selected, you're actually using the exact same code-base as the Table control.

So the real question is: "When should I use Editable vs. Read-Only?"

My answer to that question is:

- If you have a small dataset, always use Editable. This will greatly simplify things.
- If you have a large dataset, but you need to allow inline editing, use Editable.
- If you have a large dataset, and you do not need to allow inline editing, I would still recommend using Editable mode unless performance becomes an issue. The reason I say that is Read-Only mode treats every control in your table as output text and ignores some configurations that you might have considered important when building your table. Additionally, it makes it complicated to use modal displays inside of your table.

So to summarize, you should really only use Read-Only mode as a last resort. Even then, there are other approaches for improving table performance, including the Server-Side loading option.

For more information, please visit [this link](https://support.bp-3.com/hc/en-us/articles/208926177-Lighter-Faster-Using-Table-Controls-in-Non-Editable-Mode).

Hope that helps,

Gordon